# Block Google's 'People also ask' snippets?

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know if there's a way to block google's 'People also ask' snippets? This is what I have on my ublock origin list but it does not seem to work.

I compiled this all together from multiple searches.
I swear, I've tried zapping this element in ublock origin but it doesn't work.

```
    www.google.com##.mw div[jsl^="$t"][jsl$="0;"][class^="r-"]
    www.google.com##div[class^="r-inw"]
    www.google.com##.exp-outline
    www.google.com##.ads-ad
    google.*##[id^="eob_"]
    google.com##.AUiS2
    google.com##.exp-outline
```

Please share any thoughts on how to do this.

Comment: This question is offtopic here. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115038/how-to-stop-googles-people-also-search-for

Comment: Maybe? It's about using uBlock rules to block this site element. So the problem and solution are both local to the PC I think.